# how to lauch fragmentActivity as part of screen if i click on listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I am using fragments in place of tabs and on the above i am showing a listview,if i click on the particular list coloumn then a new fragmentActivity is launch due to new activity is launched the tabs(fragments) is gone but i want the tabs(fragments) should remain there in the new screen too, what should i do..

the activity code is below.

public class FriendsFragment  extends ListFragment{

```
public static String[] friendsaddoptions=new String[]{
    "Fox User","FaceBook","Email","Twiter","SMS"
};


ListView listview;
Friends_Names_List_Adapter friendsnameslistadapter;
JSONArray dataJsonObject;
Button add;
Button back;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list, container,false);
    listview=(ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    add=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_add);

    back=(Button)view. findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    back.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    FriendsFragmentData dataobserver=new FriendsFragmentData();
    ServerManager.getInstance().addObserver(dataobserver);
    ServerManager.getInstance().readLoopForFriends_Names_List(AppConstances.Friends_Names_List);

    if(friendsnameslistadapter==null)
        friendsnameslistadapter=new Friends_Names_List_Adapter(getActivity(), new JSONArray());
    listview.setAdapter(friendsnameslistadapter);

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       /*Intent in=new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), FriendsNamesAddActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);*/
            ArrayAdapter< String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.friends_add_listitem,R.id.friends_add_option,friendsaddoptions);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            if(adapter!=null)
                back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),FoxUserActivity.class);    
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });


            if(adapter!=null)
            {
                add.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }

    });
```

How to Launch FragmentActivity as a part of screen so that tabs(Fragments) is remain visible for every activity .